# How to show Badge on Fab?

Tags: material-ui

How could I show a `Badge` on `Fab` button? I tried it like this, but it displays it behind my content, as i can see it in DOM.

```
<Badge badgeContent={addedItems} color="secondary">
    <Fab
        variant="extended"
        color="primary"
        aria-label="add"
            onClick={handleAdd}
    >
        <Icon>shopping_cart</Icon>
    </Fab>
</Badge>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ok, `addedItems` value is probably 0, which causes the badge to be invisible. 
You can refer to the below CodeSandbox example with your code, I hard coded `badgeContent` to be greater than 0 and it works.

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]

---

If `addedItems` value is the issue and that is not your desired behavior, you can provide `showZero={true}` prop to Badge:

```
<Badge showZero={true} badgeContent={addedItems} color="secondary">
```